# Querying across databases with Azure SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to insert data from one database table into another database table (on the same server) in Azure SQL. I see the following:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/

This describes that I should be able to do the following:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE RemoteReferenceData
WITH
(
    TYPE=RDBMS,
    LOCATION='myserver.database.windows.net',
    DATABASE_NAME='_2016-09-07-17412',
    CREDENTIAL= SqlUser
);

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[RemotePhotos](
    [PhotoId] int NOT NULL,
    [Url] nvarchar(max) NULL,
)
WITH
(
    DATA_SOURCE = RemoteReferenceData
);
```

However I get the following when I run this:

> The specified credential cannot be found.

How can I go about creating a credential for this purpose?  Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: This might help https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt270260.aspx

Comment: I resolved this error by right-clicking on "Security > Add > New Item... > Credential"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what I ended up with:

```
-- Cleanup
DROP EXTERNAL TABLE OldPhoto
DROP EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE RemoteReferenceData
DROP DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL credentialName
DROP MASTER KEY
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password';

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL credentialName
WITH IDENTITY = 'credentialName',
SECRET = 'password';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE RemoteReferenceData
WITH
(
    TYPE=RDBMS,
    LOCATION='myserver.database.windows.net',
    DATABASE_NAME='mydb',
    CREDENTIAL= credentialName
);

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dbo.OldPhoto(
    [PhotoId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Url] [nvarchar](300) NULL
)
WITH
(
    DATA_SOURCE = RemoteReferenceData
);

Select top 20 * from dbo.OldPhoto
```

The challenging bits were:

- I was pulling data from a backup with a table that had the same name.  I had to rename the source table.
- The table creation has to match the schema of the current table in the external source.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning here that the credential that I used had the username and password of a valid SQL server account with permissions to select records from the source database.